# How to serialize a Linq to Sql object graph without hiding the child's "Parent" member

Tags: linq-to-sql, xml-serialization

Without hiding the Child object's reference to the Parent object, has anyone been able to use an XmlSerializer() object to move a Linq to SQL object to an XML document, or is the only appropriate way of handling this to create a custom serialization/deserialization class to handle moving the data to/from the xml document?

I don't like the idea of hiding the child object's reference to the parent object is why I'm asking.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the reference internal solves this problem for JSON serialization. You can try it to see if it would work for XML serialization too.

Comment: It does, the issue is that you don't get the child to parent object graph.  For now, with the issue I had, it works... but for other jobs, I'll have to just use linq 2 sql as a data storage/retrieval mechanism, and use POCO objects to do the serialization.